# im getting CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I'm getting a `CORS` header missing error. I can't modify the code of the back end web service, I can only change the client side application.

I can add the "`Allow control allow origin`" addon on google chrome but I don't want to install the add on all the clients to access the api. How can i change my `AngularJS` code so that I will not get this issue?

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('url', {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic a2VybmVsc3B==' }
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.names = response.data;
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: your server should send that header telling about the allowed origins.

Comment: It's because of your have different API server, So you can add header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` in your back-end server.

Comment: im able to resove this issue by adding addon in google chrome , then y cant i write code in front end application for that for cors header missing

Comment: @Swapna You don't have to worry about the addons. They are allowed to get the data like postman. They can fetch data without any cors error.

Comment: The only way you can do this is by using a proxy. ***All the suggestions to use jsonp will not work*** since jsonp does not support headers

Comment: what do u mean by proxy, i didn't get you

Comment: a server side script on a server you control that makes a cURL request to remote api or a third party service. Do a web search

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but how would you know the Content type? Can you add an entry in headers like `'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` ?

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422457/im-getting-cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing-in-angularjs#comment70051086_41422457) in the comments, you will have to use a proxy, or some sort of proxy. There is no way around this.

However, it is fairly straightforward: **make the server that serves the angularjs application do the api call.**

First, you have to understand what server and client is. Afterwards, you need to understand that your angularjs application is *served* from a server. Your angularjs application can make http requests to that server, which will in turn make the call to the api, and return the result to the client:

[image: crudely drawn diagram]

I am somewhat assuming a Node server is serving your angularjs application, but any server can do the same, it will be able to make the http request without being a cross origin request.

---

In your case, when you do the `url` call, instead, call the server that serves your application, and then, from that server, create a service that will call the external api.

Comment: finally a sane answer!

Comment: worth mentioning that there are third party proxy services also. Personally I don't like using no-name ones but that option does exist

Comment: good point. However I rarely (never) use those, hence I am a bit hesitant to explain about that. will update if I feel I can add something worthwhile

Comment: I have used several different ones that Yahoo supported. One is dead , was called pipes and was pretty cool. The other YQL is still alive and can do a lot of different things....xml to json, html scraper , straight json retrieval among a few

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. 
Angular at front makes requests to backend. 
Nginx is the proxy. So I added this line to my nginx config

```
location /database/ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        <other_lines>
}
```

This solved my CORSs issue.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using **IIS** Web server please add below config to your `web.config` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**If you dont have access to backend** use `$http.jsonp(url)` instead of `$http.get(url)`

Comment: OP clearly stated they don't have back end access. How is this going to help?